# Simple DC generator

Tags: dc-generator

[image]

This is a question related to a simple DC generator. Both the options (2) and (3) appear to be correct.

Do I have any misconceptions?

Comment: Actually, that is a generator. Not a motor.

Comment: sorry, my bad, it’s a simple generator

Comment: Almost no difference between "motor" and "generator" here.  If "load" was changed to a battery, the thing would spin.  Old locomotives have main generators exactly like this (but with 6-10 poles instead of 2, and an electromagnet for the stationery field) and the main generator is used as the starter motor to crank the engine.

Answer (score 1):

Only affirmation 3 is true. In case 1 the magnetic force is acting downward not upward. For each action is a reaction of opposite side. Meaning that if this generator is "pushing" electrons while turning AB segment upward, then assuredly, the magnets will induce a force on the AB segment downward, resisting the flow of electrons.

View another way, in a generator the rotor is forced to turn (in this case counterclockwise). This rotation involve movement of the wire segment into the magnetic field. Such arrangement will induce a voltage at the extremities of that wire segment. Because the wire segment is in a closed loop (made with the other segment CD and all the rest of the wiring) this voltage will "push" a flow of electron circulating in the loop. Now you are creating an electromagnet formed by that induced current in the wire loop. That newly created magnetic field will oppose the existing field, hence induce a counter force resisting the movement. It is called the counter-electromotive force.

In case 2 the commutator would reverse the direction of current on the **load** such that the current will **always** be in the same direction. The coil here consist of the loop rotating in the magnetic field. While it is true that the current will reverse direction when a complete 1/2 rotational turn is done, it is not caused by the commutator but rather by the fact that each segment directional speed vary from positive maximum to negative maximum magnetic field due to its rotational movement while the magnetic field is fixed. Hence, inducing an alternating voltage. The commutator here will act as a mechanical rectifier, constantly changing the AC voltage polarity for each 1/2 turn. The signal seen on the load will be a rectified AC signal. Hence (3) the current flowing on the load is an unsteady D.C.

The answer is C. (3) only

Comment: Please don't provide solutions to homework questions where the OP has not shown a substantial effort to solve it themselves. In this case the OP needs to justify their answer and explain their understanding rather than provide a guess as to the correct answer.